# how to fit an I mage to jumbotron in bootsrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having my image size of width 1800px and height 200px i want to create a jumbotron where the image should fit to that jumbotron means the jumbotron size should also be that so I can see my full picture and it should also be responsive

my Code..

```
<style>
    .jumbotron1{
    background-image:  url(/img/ffHeadernologo.png);
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom: 11.1111% /* ( 1800 / 200 ) = 9; 100 / 9 = 11.1111 */
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

What I wants to do is..

This my background

[image]

and I also have logo as follow

[image]

the logo should be in another div and backround has been set as above its working fine.

I want the result like this

[image]

How can I do that the above solution is not working great with this what to do?

any suggestions I have seen the earlier Same Question but its not working so I have asked it again.

in third image the black line has been removed that has to be there.
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the `responsive-img` class to the class attribute of your image tag

**Edit:**

Because you are using `background-image` us this css

CSS

```
<style>
    .jumbotron1{
        background-image:  url(/img/ffHeadernologo.png);
        background-size: cover;
        text-align: center;
        width:100%;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

note that this will keep the aspect ratio intact but if the screen is taller than that aspect ratio it will show space above and below, on the other hand if the screen is skinnier than that aspect ratio it will crop the right hand side of the image

**EDIT:**

It seems you just want a background image. I that case I suggest that you just use the following css

```
body { 
    background: url(/img/ffHeadernologo.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**EDIT:**

You are actually trying to make a header with a background. To do that you can use this

CSS

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/23xfjfrp/22/))

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/1800x200/225599/ffffff) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I am not using tag I am giving it as background

Comment: its Working fine but I want to set another div in that div so its not working over there how can I do that?

Comment: actually this is my header background my body background is different so will my body background overright it or what will happen

Answer (score 0):

Check this example i simply used the background:url() technique

```html
      <html>

<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
 .jumbotron{ background: url(http://cdn.superbwallpapers.com/wallpapers/vector/blue-polygon-28641-1920x1080.jpg);}.jumbotron{width:100%;height:100%}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>

<div class='jumbotron'>Hell</div>

</div>

</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I am using the same but my image is not fit to the jumbotron

Comment: do you want to make the jumbotron dimensions same as the image's dimensions , why you are using the jumbotron for it ? make a DIV than

Comment: how to do it with div ? my image should be in the background that  div should fit exactly to the image